# Geolocation Field - Map Marker in Views

Tags: views, 8, location, google-maps

I'm trying to show a map with multiple markers with the help of Views and [Geolocation](https://www.drupal.org/project/geolocation) field. It would be nice for example if I can show the image in the tooltip display of the marker. But when I add an image as a field to achieve this, the image automatically gets selected as the icon source field by default (See Views UI - FORMAT - Advanced settings). Is it possible change this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a display in your content type where you will put the field that you want to show in the tooltip.

Home » Administration » Structure » Content types » YOUR CONTENT TYPE » Manage display

Then in your view select in the format to show Content and in the View mode the display that you created before with your fields.

Comment: @JorgeMontoya I'm happy for you, this Geolocation module give a lot of headaches a few months ago. :-D God luck in your project.

Answer (score 0):

In views you can hide image field and it will't be shown on map.
In advanced settings you can change custom icon which you want to be shown on map and for tooltip can add custom text or title or body.